# Bootstrap 3 with Bootstrap Tags Input and typeahead don't show the tags inside input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 with Bootstrap Tags Input and typeahead but it doesn't show the tags inside the input.

It is difficult to explain... It is better to see in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/claudiosw/5cww4fcg/3/

I have tried to use typeahead.js but the result was the same.

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" value="Test1,Test2" data-role="tagsinput" />


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 

      $('input').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
          source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you expect to see/happen when typing in your input (and what you want to type)?

Comment: @ganders, it is like what Jaqen did. So, it seems that the question is already answered. Either way thanks to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix it do two things:

1. To show the tags inside the input dont use both `data-role="tagsinput"` and `tagsinput()`. Instead, init it only with in the js.
2. To clear the plaintext after a tag is added you should add:

   ```
   afterSelect: function() {
       this.$element[0].value = "";
   }
   ```

   to the `tagsinput()` options.

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w133uvo9/)

Comment: Jippy, you saved my day. I am spending hours with reasearching and testing why my search function was not called.

Your tipp to yust remove the data-roles was the solution